# mypy doesn't realize a dataclass's member is really what it is via `__post_init__`

Tags: python, mypy

I have a `dataclass` that contains a `list[tuple[str,str]]`, and I'd like to be able to initialize with a `dict[str,str]` too. Programmatically it's this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foobar:
    list_of_tuples: list[tuple[str, str]]

    def __post_init__(self):
        if isinstance(self.list_of_tuples, dict):
            self.list_of_tuples = list(self.list_of_tuples.items())


Foobar({"a": "b"})
```

but [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) isn't happy:

```
e.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "Foobar" has incompatible type "dict[str, str]"; expected "list[tuple[str, str]]"  [arg-type]
```

mypy doesn't realize I transform the `dict` to `list[tuple]` straight after initialization.

Unfortunately, there's no `__pre_init__` for dataclasses. I'd like to avoid overriding `__init__()` as well, if possible.

Any hints?

Comment: The type hint for the autogenerated `__init__` method is derived from the field. `dataclass` doesn't try to make any inferences from the definition of `__post_init__` to modify it.

Comment: (Which is to say, you'd have to define `__init__` explicitly to provide an accurate type hint for this use case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to initialize an object with a list of `dict`s, define a class method to do it explicitly.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foobar:
    list_of_tuples: list[tuple[str, str]]

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: dict[str, str]):
        return cls(list_of_tuples=list(d.items()))



fb = Foobar.from_dict({"a": "b"})
```